# Configure Mysql 5.7 with Travis CI

Tags: continuous-integration, travis-ci, mysql-5.7

I can't run my tests on Travis CI because i can't find a way to setup mysql 5.7 in container.

I've found this gist https://gist.github.com/BenMorel/d981f25ead0926a0cb6d explaining a configuration method for `travis.yml`. Here are the commands :

```bash
sudo apt-get remove --purge "^mysql.*"
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql
sudo rm -rf /var/log/mysql
echo mysql-apt-config mysql-apt-config/enable-repo select mysql-5.7-dmr | sudo debconf-set-selections
wget http://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.2.1-1ubuntu12.04_all.deb
sudo dpkg --install mysql-apt-config_0.2.1-1ubuntu12.04_all.deb
sudo apt-get update -q
sudo apt-get install -q -y -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" mysql-server
```

right after that, I'm doing :

```bash
$ mysql -uroot < tests/ApiBundle/Datas/dump_test.sql
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

Why ?? I've tried so many things… And Google is definitely not my friend for this issue…

Comment: Have you tried `sudo mysql -uroot < tests/ApiBundle/Datas/dump_test.sql`?

Comment: yes I did… same error !

Comment: Have you tried using `Docker`? Check this: https://medium.com/@mtparet/install-mysql-server-5-7-on-travis-96f2ebc0f339

Comment: Since the time I posted this, of course I did :), and still do every time I face the same kind of issue with CI / development / tests run. As everyone should nowadays. Still, I don't want or should update this question nor the answers IMHO as they still may be useful to anyone trying to do that out of containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the current docs, you only need to enable sudo, and add the following config in your `.travis.yml` file

```
addons:
  apt:
   sources:
    - mysql-5.7-trusty
   packages:
    - mysql-server
    - mysql-client
```

Source https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/database-setup/#MySQL-5.7

Answer (score 8):

Ok I've found out how to reinstall MySQL 5.6 in Travis CI default container.

Here is what is needed in `.travis.yml`:

```yaml
services:
  - mysql
sudo: true
before_script:
  - bash .travis.install-mysql-5.7.sh
```

And here is the `.travis.install-mysql-5.7.sh` (edited thanks to @codyzu answer):

```bash
echo mysql-apt-config mysql-apt-config/select-server select mysql-5.7 | sudo debconf-set-selections
wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.7.3-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg --install mysql-apt-config_0.7.3-1_all.deb
sudo apt-get update -q
sudo apt-get install -q -y --allow-unauthenticated -o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confnew mysql-server
sudo mysql_upgrade
```

I hope it would help anyone facing the same issue !

Comment: In cases where sysem works with MySQL users (or something similar), calling `sudo mysql_upgrade` as the last step of `.travis.install-mysql-5.7.sh` is required.

Comment: This isnt working for me, im getting dependency problems: `mysql-server depends on mysql-community-server (= 5.7.8-rc-1ubuntu12.04); however:
  Package mysql-community-server is not configured yet.`

Comment: I had to add this to get it to work properly for me:

    sudo mysql_upgrade -u root
    sudo service mysql restart

Comment: This was broken because mysql-5.7-dmr no longer exists. Here is my (now) [working script](https://github.com/codyzu/jasql/blob/a2b42fc2a97c9fee44e4f967b38ac2a3b6b13b6c/.travis.install-mysql-5.7.sh)

Comment: I updated your answer FYI because this failed due to `WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!` so had to pass the `--allow-unauthenticated` to get it to install.